# targeting classes with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Need to pass information from one class to another in a way that will validate. Current approach is a mess- works but does not validate.
I need to pass text inside a p tag to another element on the page. Right now i'm using a tag attributes to pass this info along. Super messy.

```
<div class="element-item">
 <div class="text-panel">
  <div class="text-cell">
  <a class="ajax" href="ajax/bkdesks.html" id="Brooklyn Desks" dir="BROOKLYN, NY">
<p class="link"><img src="img/chainlink.png" width="60" height="60" alt="link"  alt=""/></p>
<p class="name">Brooklyn Desks</p>
<p class="dir">Brooklyn, NY</p>
</a>
</div>
</div>
```

And then jQuery:

```
$('.ajax').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
$('#projects-head .titlehead').text($(this).attr('id'));
$('#projects-head .subhead').text($(this).attr('dir'));
$('#project').load($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

titlehead and subhead are the other elements on the page whose content is being replaced. I would much rather grab the contents of the p tags below than put everything in the a id & dir. But i cant figure out the jquery to target them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `p.name` and `p.dir` elements are descendant elements of the clicked `.ajax` element so you can use .find()

```
$('.ajax').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();var $this = $(this);
    $('#projects-head .titlehead').text($(this).find('.name').html());
    $('#projects-head .subhead').text($(this).find('.dir').html());
    $('#project').load($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

Comment: yup! that did it. I had tried something similiar i just didnt add the .html to the end. That totally fixes it- thanks much for the reply